# Compile Command Line Binary for iPhone in Xcode (for Jailbroken iOS)

Tags: iphone, xcode, compilation, binary, arm

I want to compile a tool I've made that runs on my computer to also run on my iPhone through Xcode. I know it's possible but I can't figure it out, does anyone here know how to do this?

I know how to make regular apps I've made work on my Jailbroken iPhone, and I know all about permissions and code signing.  I just want to get the code for my command line tool to compile for the iPhone.

Comment: Must it be Xcode? What about using gcc?

Answer (score -2):

For a bash script you could use system:

```
system ("echo This is bash!")
```

If it's objective C (Mac) then porting shouldn't be too hard but yes it can be difficult!

If this isn't what you were looking for, your question was WAY to vague.